# How can i access this variable out side the function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, function-call

```
function testing() {
  var test = function() {
    console.log("hi");
  };
  return test;
}
testing.test;
```

this doesn't console the content of the variable test.

Comment: You cannot access the `test` variable outside the function, it's a *local* variable. However the function returns its value, so you can just call it to get the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can just execute the test function after executing the testing function:

```js
function testing() {
  var test = function() {
    console.log("hi");
  };
  return test;
}
testing()();
```

If you want to use `testing` like an object, you can return one:

```js
function testing() {
  var test = function() {
    console.log("hi");
  };
  return {test:test};
}
testing().test();
```

Comment: Damn I wasted time on explaining all different ways. :(

Comment: Hm, no answer is a waste of time :-)

Comment: Lol only if I was faster. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to deal with this problem, here are some of them,

Return the variable itself, and run the function,

```
function testing() {
  var test = function() {
    console.log("hi");
  };
  return test;
}
testing()(); // <-- weird as heck, testing() returns a function, and we execute it.
```

Run the function and return the variable,

```
function testing() {
  var test = function() {
    console.log("hi");
  };
  return test();
}
testing();
```

Turn it into an object,

```
var testing = {
  test: function(){ console.log("hi") }
}

testing.test() // <-- access the test however you want.
```

Return an object,

```
function testing() {
  return {
    test: function() {
     console.log("hi");
    };
}
testing().test // <-- this is a function, execute it as you wish
```

Turn it into a prototype.

```
function Testing(){}
Testing.prototype.test = function() {
 console.log("hi");
};
new Testing().test() // access it
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the `test` function

```js
function testing() {
  var test = function() {
    console.log("hi");
  };
  return test(); // changed here
}
testing();
```

Otherwise create an object `testing` & let `test` be a method of that object

```js
var testing = {
  test: function() {
    console.log("hi");
  }

}
testing.test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `testing()` function returns another function. You must assign the return value to a variable and then call that function to get the result that your looking for:

```
function testing() {
  var test = function() {
    console.log("hi");
  };
  return test;
}
var test = testing();
test()

//Or alternatively:
testing()();
```

Comment: but if there is more than one variale inside the function and we want to access all of them